# How can I access the properties of an object inside an object?

Tags: java, mongodb, object, gson

I have an object Pelicula like this:

```
public class Pelicula {
    private String popularity;
    private Object belongs_to_collection;

    public Pelicula() {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }


    public String getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }   

    public Object getBelongs_to_collection() {
        return belongs_to_collection;
    }

}
```

This object is the conversion of a mongodb document to an object Pelicula using Gson, which contains some strings and an object belongs_to_collection.

```
{
  "adult": false,
  "backdrop_path": "/8SqBiesvo1rh9P1hbJTmnVum6jv.jpg",
  "belongs_to_collection": {
    "id": 304378,
    "name": "Independence Day - Colección",
    "poster_path": "/diCxphvzqas0Tr5eq7tLUzg5M7d.jpg",
    "backdrop_path": "/p7oqa94XgNGVMazXwR49QfyGgtx.jpg"
  },
  "budget": 165000000 
...
```

For create the objects I use this function:

```
 public List getAllMovies() {
        List<Pelicula> allMovies = new ArrayList();
        Pelicula movie;
        for (Document p : getCollection().find()) {
            movie = getGson().fromJson(p.toJson(), Pelicula.class);
            allMovies.add(movie);

        }
        System.out.println(allMovies.get(0).getPopularity());
        return allMovies;
    }
```

As you can see I can print the property popularity. Also, I can print the object belongs_to_collection of the object Pelicula using toString.

The question is: Can I access the properties of belongs_to_collection one by one without creating an object belongs_to_collection that inherits Pelicula?

Comment: A side question: How will be an Pelicula object instanciated, when no setter exists for a private property?

Comment: @reporter GSON uses reflection to fill in values.

Comment: You can either create a `TypeAdapter` or create a representation of `belongs_to_collection`.

Comment: This is the magic of Gson (byGoogle).
        Pelicula movie;
        for (Document p : getCollection().find()) {
            movie = getGson().fromJson(p.toJson(), Pelicula.class);
            allMovies.add(movie);

        }
When the Pelicula movie object is created, Gson convert a mongoDB document to a Pelicula object.

Comment: @kalsowerus Can you put an example of TypeAdapter? I don't know what is.

Comment: You can find many examples of GSON `TypeAdapter`s on the interweb, but creating a new Object is definitely easier.